# Different results of running metapost on two systems

Tags: metapost

I have a problem with a metapost and LaTeX file.

I use LaTeX and metapost on two different macs, both with the same version of OS X (10.9.5) and both with, as far as I can tell the same installation of MacTeX.  On both systems, the metapost file compiles correctly.

On one of the systems the LaTeX file compiles to produce a document with the graphic correctly positioned.  On the other system LaTeX produces a document with the graphic shifted to the northeast.

I have included each of the .pdf files. I can provide .tex and .mp files if needed. Can someone give me an idea of why this is happening, and how to correct it?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-CVsMHLl85bSGozWHdmOWRpRU0/edit?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-CVsMHLl85bdmhOUGQzUFh5azQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: This is probably caused by different versions of the `xetex.def` file which controls clipping and placement of graphics.  Did you try updating them both to the latest level?  [Instructions here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution/55438#55438).